# What is range of Cloudant geospatial point's nearest neighbour search

Tags: cloudant, nearest-neighbor

I am using cloudant db for geospatial index. Cloudant has Nearest neighbor search for point. It has parameter to limit the no of results. But what is range of nearest neighbor. I have a requirement to search with in 500 mts. How can achieve the same in cloudant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the range by combining the nearest neighbor parameter with a geometry parameter. For example, the following query will find all docs within 500 meters of the specified lat/long:

```
https://account.cloudant.com/yourDatabaseName
/_design/yourDesignDocName/
_geo/yourGeoIndexName
?lat=37.41511369
&lon=-122.2099019
&radius=500
&relation=contains
&nearest=true
```

More information:

https://docs.cloudant.com/geo.html

**Update**: Be sure to add `&relation=contains` to ensure the results only include locations within the radius. I have updated the example above. If relation is not included then nearest neighbor will return *"all GeoJSON documents in the database whose order is measured by the distance to the query point."*

See the documentation for other relation types (i.e. contains, crosses, overlaps, etc.)